# Distance Learning Mindstorms web-based software

Tags: ev3, mindstorms

I am a Technology education teacher from NJ and I use Lego Mindstorms for my 8th-grade robotics class. Since we are doing distance learning (teaching from home) my students have not been able to continue their curriculum as the software and robots are at school. Is there a web-based program where the students can code with block-based coding (not scratch) like in the normal downloadable software and run virtual tests of their code? Kind of like the virtual brick or virtual world software you can purchase but a web-based version so my students can still learn how and explore Mindstorms like we would in the classroom. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Here's [Microsoft Makecode](https://makecode.mindstorms.com/). It is full of tutorials for the EV3, such as:

• Example programs

• How certain sensors work

• How certain code blocks work

• Instructions for EV3 robots

• And much more.

Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I did see that option, but I wasn't a huge fan. I like the block style code for at least a little intro as I have a wide range of abilities in my classes. This isn't a horrible option but it is scratch based and there is no option to test the code to see what the robot physically does. There is an option to see the brick move the motors and sensors, but I think seeing the robot actually move is more beneficial to the students.

Comment: @Ryan Can't you teach them how to download the actual software?

Comment: Nevermind, iOS devices are not compatible with it unfortunately. Also, do they even have the EV3 with them at home?

Comment: Our students are not 1:1 so they have to use their personal computers so downloading any software is not an option unfortunately since not everyone has the same device it would cause compatibility issues. No they do not have their EV3 robots at home. I was trying to find a web based option where they could code using the block style code like in the Mindstorms software where they could then run their robot in a virtual world sort of like what can be done with RobotC but web based. I know this is asking a lot but I want to try to keep them learning as close to the school environment as possible

Comment: @Ryan I'm sorry, I don't know any website that meets all of the criteria. I will do a few google searches to see if I can find anything else. You should search too.

Comment: No worries thank you, I have been looking myself and didn't have any luck yet

Comment: @Ryan also, it's not possible to have a virtual EV3 studio thing where the EV3 can actually move its motors and you can see what's going on. Only real-life can show that, and software like stud.io can only *show* the model in it's inactive state and show instructions, but it cannot actually test how it moves and it's physics. It would not be possible to stuff it all in a single website, which means that Microsoft Makecode is your best bet.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Thats what I had found as well unfortunately, back to the drawing board.

Answer (score 0):

There is a program called Robot Virtual Worlds:
http://www.robotvirtualworlds.com/

... but it is a downloaded program vs. web based.  You might be able to use a remote desktop sharing program (VNC, Skype, Zoom, MS Teams, Team Center, etc.) to access remotely, or contact them if they're considering a "cloud hosted" option.

They do offer a free trial, so you can always experiment to see if it works at all for you.

Comment: VMs with students!?!? Are you kidding me? I think that you're bringing this a little too far, and hopefully it supports almost all video cards that currently exist, otherwise it still may be a problem. I don't see how you're going to inject a VM into another student's computer, and the OP does not look like an advanced computer technician (or whatever you need to be to manipulate VMs) so I don't think it's possible.

Comment: Not suggesting anything about VMs.  The Remote Desktop would allow OP to install the program on a school PC and then "share" it with students.  It would probably involve school IT support, and not sure how well the remote connection may work.  However, it offers a virtual LEGO robot that can be programmed without physical hardware, using same/similar programming tools as the "real" robot.  The best case scenario would be if the RVW developers could offer a web based client (cloud hosted) vs. download only.

Comment: @mindstormsboi You may not be aware of this, but the tone in your comment above reads a bit aggressive to me. I'd hate for folks to get the wrong impression of you. Please be more considerate of your tone when commenting in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should try [CoderZ](https://gocoderz.com/). I think that it would fill your requirements. An online coding environment where you can also see the robots virtually move as they have been programmed. I have never actually used this before but I think that you should have a look at it. Happy Programming.

Comment: Welcome to Bricks.SE! Do you have any relationship with CoderZ? It's not a problem if you do, but we do ask that you disclose this. I am curious to understand why you are recommending this product if you haven't used it before.

Comment: In answer to your question. I do not have any relationship with CoderZ. Also, I didn't say I was recommending it, I just said to perhaps try it, although I understand that it could be taken as recommending it.(I just wanted to try and help someone, and I think that CoderZ fitted what he asked for).

Comment: Thanks for sharing. This software looks like a potential solution to me. It was flagged as possible spam, so I wanted to make sure that this was a genuine recommendation of this product. Thanks for helping out!